# Azure Certificate roll over

Tags: azure, certificate, rollover

I have integrated our app with Azure Active Directory. I am getting emails from Microsoft that I should review the certificates until August 15th. The idea is that I don't know what and why should I do something, since I didn't do anything when I created the apps. I am using oauth2 with id and secret. Can anyone help?